# mysql select where in select as variable

Tags: php, mysql, sql

i have the following select statement

```
SELECT
    a.firstname name,
    m.date time
FROM
    account a
    LEFT JOIN memberships m ON a.id = m.account_id
WHERE
    a.is_active = 1
```

i am trying check and see if the user has an active membership (there could be more than one, but one is all i need as proof) and if so then set the variable true or the id or something, if not then false (or null or whatever)

here is what i have so far

```
SELECT
    a.firstname name,
    p.date time
    m.id active_membership
FROM
    account a
    LEFT JOIN profile p ON a.id = p.account_id
WHERE
    a.id IN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id FROM memberships WHERE active = 1)
AND
    a.is_active = 1
```

so the results i am trying to get would be
name, time, active_membership
foo, 10:00, null
bar, 14:00, 223(id or anything)

i got everything working accept for the where in part...

Comment: Does memberships have more than one column?

Comment: It seems you need [`EXISTS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) here.

Comment: ya membership has a lot more columns

Comment: You can always use a `RIGHT JOIN` to force only records that have an associated account to load.

Comment: @tadman that won't work, that will prevent the whole selection altogether

Comment: So you want the intersection of active accounts **and** active memberships **with** profile information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need another `LEFT JOIN`.

```
SELECT
    a.firstname name,
    p.date time,
    IF(m.account_id IS NULL, "No", "Yes") active_membership
FROM account a
LEFT JOIN profile p ON a.id = p.account_id
LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT account_id
           FROM memberships
           WHERE active = 1) m ON a.id = m.account_id
WHERE a.is_active = 1
```

Comment: Why can't you just `LEFT JOIN memberships m ON a.id=m.account_id AND m.active=1`?

Comment: Because if someone has multiple memberships, that will create multiple rows in the result.

Comment: You could use that, but then you need to add `GROUP BY a.id` at the end.

Comment: Nothing `GROUP BY` couldn't fix, but that's good observation.

Comment: I prefer to use `DISTINCT` in the subquery, because it makes the cross product in the `JOIN` smaller.